# Why isn't my anonymous class action listener not working to exit the Java GUI?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

ob1 is a JButton, and when clicked on a dialog will pop up. Once it pops up, the pop-up window will say "Hello There" and an "Hi" button underneath. When "Hi" is clicked on, I would like it to exit the GUI all together. But here it seem like I've done everything correctly, but I don't understand why it's not working. Please help.

Thank you

```
ob1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            JDialog jd = new JDialog(); //Pop-Up window
            jd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jd.setSize(350, 150);
            jd.setModal(true);
            JPanel jp = new JPanel();
            jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            JLabel jl = new JLabel("Hello there");
            JButton jb3 = new JButton("Hi");
            jp.add(jl);
            jp.add(jb3);
            jd.add(jp);
            jd.setVisible(true);

            //acition listener for the Hi button and when clicked on supposed to exit the GUI
            jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to dispose the jdialog also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the dialog is modal...

```
jd.setModal(true);
```

The code will stop at...

```
jd.setVisible(true);
```

Until the dialog is closed, meaning that...

```
//acition listener for the Hi button and when clicked on supposed to exit the GUI
jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```

Is not called until AFTER the dialog is closed, meaning that the `ActionListener` is not registered to the button until AFTER the dialog is closed, which is kind of meaningless...

Switch those two lines...

```
jb3.addActionListener(...);
jd.setVisible(true);
```

Take a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details...

ps- You don't actually need the `ActionListener`, you can simply call `System.exit(0)` after the `setVisible` call, but you will the `JButton` to dispose of the dialog.

pps- You could simply use a `JOptionPane` to achieve the same result in less lines of code ;)

**Updated...**

By it's nature, `JOptionPane.showXxx` is a blocking method, until the dialog it shows is closed, the method will not return.

This means that you can assume that one the method returns, the dialog has been closed an on the user pressed "OK"...

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jf, "Hello there", "Window", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: You can't (okay you could, but you won't like the solution).  Once the `showMessageDialog` returns, you can automatically assume that `OK` was clicked (cause the only thing else they can do is close the dialog with the "x" button)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution....

```
Exit() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,500);

    ob1 = new JButton("Hi");
    ob1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            final JDialog jd = new JDialog(); // Pop-Up window
            jd.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            jd.setSize(350, 150);
            jd.setModal(true);
            JPanel jp = new JPanel();
            jp.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jp, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            JLabel jl = new JLabel("Hello there");
            JButton jb3 = new JButton("Hi");

            jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    System.out.println("Hello...");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

            jp.add(jl);
            jp.add(jb3);
            jd.add(jp);
            jd.setVisible(true); //It should be after the action listener....
        }
    });

    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.add(ob1);

    add(pane);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Hi...");
    new Exit();
}
```

You must have to add the actionListener before setVisible() is being called....

Comment: There's enough "wall of codes" on the internet that represent a good portion of the questions asked by the less experienced, an attempt to educate the poor OP would help them not only solve their problem, but help them identify good code in the future and maybe show them resources they could use in the future to solve there own problems - IMHO